# Как лучше всего хранить данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Мне надо хранить в БД подписки(id - кого я читаю).
Какой лучше всего сделать тип для этого и как сохранять данные, в каком виде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создай таблицу subscribers, и там сделай к примеру 2 поля, id - кто подписан и id на кого подписан

Comment: а тип VARCHAR 32 ?

Comment: @Zow, странный вопрос. Какой тип данных собираетесь хранить - такой и тип поля выбираете.

Comment: нет, для id int

Comment: Тип поля пользователя в таблице подписок - должен совпадать с типом поля пользователя из таблицы пользователей.

Comment: ахах) да ну нафиг?))

Answer (score 0):

Для кошерности создают две таблицы с такими параметрами:
Первая с **тремя** полями, (int) id номера подписки, (int) id кто подписался + (int) id на кого.

Причем первое поле id номера подписки делают автоинкрементным.

Вторая таблица например с описанием пользователей, (int) id, (varchar) name, (varchar) email и.т.д, чтобы не запутаться кто есть кто в ваших подписках id.

Дальше связываете таблицы.

Answer (score -3):

Создай таблицу, поля которые нужно к примеру: id_1 и id_2. Так как там будут храниться цифры, то тип integer(int).